# Launching notification with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'd like to be able to notify the user weekly to do a task. I know what I need to do but don't know how to do it. I need to somehow pass the commented out code (last line) to the AlarmManager.

```
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = notiType+" reminder for "+projName;
        CharSequence contentText = "Take your photo now!";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProjectPreview.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("projname", "asdsad");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), contentIntent);

        //mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell your AlarmManager to call a BroadcastReceiver (by using PendingIntent.getReceiver).

In the receiver onReceive() method, use the NotificationManager to set up the notification.